# why showing ImportError: No module named markdownx when migrating in django...?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

> ImportError: No module named markdownx

`markdown` module is installed, but still this error shows when trying to migrate with the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I am trying to load project in remote. The project folder is loaded using scp command

Comment: Share the error message

Comment: have you add markdownx in installed_apps

Comment: I'm face the same error: `ImportError: No module named markdown_deux`

Although I'm running: `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

**Try:** to install it on `remote server` using below command

```
pip install django-markdownx
```

**project settings.py**

Add `markdownx` in installed apps.

**project urls.py**

```
url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls'))
```

Comment: @naveenv, If the solution worked for you. Please select the answer else if any problem let me know via comments below. Thanks for all the cooperation.

Comment: I'm face the same error: _ImportError: No module named markdown_deux_ Although I'm running: `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @vignz.pie, *markdownx* and *markdown_deux* are different packages. It’s not the same error.

Comment: Yup, I took some time to figure that out. Thanks!